# Could not parse the remainder

Tags: django, django-templates

i want to compare num and {{buildSummary_list.number}}, but why it is not work?
And i got an error

```
Could not parse the remainder: '{{buildSummary_list.number}}' from '{{buildSummary_list.number}}'"...
```

---

```
{% for num in buildSummary_list.paginator.page_range %}
    {% ifequal num {{buildSummary_list.number}} %}
        <b>{{num}}</b>
    {% endifequal %}
    {% ifnotequal num {{buildSummary_list.number}} %}
        <a href="?page={{num}}"><b>{{num}}</b></a>
    {% endifnotequal %}

{% endfor %}
```

I want to make the pagination have effect:
pre << 1 2 **3** 4 5 6 >> next

I my code can run, can it make this effect?
thanks:D

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Inside a `{% %}` tag, variables aren't surrounded by `{{`.  Try this:

```
{% ifequal num buildSummary_list.number %}
```

Also, it looks like your two comparisons can be joined with an else:

```
{% for num in buildSummary_list.paginator.page_range %}
    {% ifequal num buildSummary_list.number %}
        <b>{{num}}</b>
    {% else %}
        <a href="?page={{num}}"><b>{{num}}</b></a>
    {% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This can also happen if you use {{ }} where you should use {% %}

Answer (score 19):

I got this error when I forgot the '' around the path to a static file

This gave the error:

```
 <link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static css/style.css %}">
```

This fixed the error:

```
 <link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
```

Answer (score 1):

The django. DjangoTemplates template backend is unable to parse a comparison operator when there is no whitespace around the operator using builtin tag if:

```
{% if foo=='bar' %}
<!-- do something -->
{% endif %}
```

raises
TemplateSyntaxError at url

Could not parse the remainder: '=='bar'' from 'foo=='bar''

At least one space is required on both sides of the == operator (So foo =='bar' and foo== 'bar' throws Could not parse the remainder: '=='bar'' from '=='bar'' and Could not parse the remainder: '==' from 'foo==', respectively). More than one space is acceptable.
This seems to affect the following boolean operators: ==, !=, <, >, <=, >=. My guess is the boolean expression tokenizer in DjangoTemplates first tries split(' ') then ultimately evals [0][1][2] (but I haven't actually looked at the source to verify this).

Answer (score 1):

thats so easy you should not write like this

```py
{% if foo=='bar' %}
<!-- do something -->
{% endif %}
```

you should write your code like this

```py
{% if foo == 'bar' %}
<!-- do something -->
{% endif %}
```

pay attention to the space before ==

Answer (score 1):

When you are dealing with comparison operator `==` within templates, make sure you have spaces before and after `==` operator. This could be one of the reason for above error.
For ex. `category.slug == c.slug`

Answer (score 0):

```
django 2.2 relative URL

**Correct**

<a href="{% url 'urlapp:other' %}">go to other page </a>
<br/>
<a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}"> admin page</a>

**error inccorect code some white space still get same error ** 

<a href="{% url 'urlapp:other' %}">go to other page </a>
<br/>
<a href="{% url 'urlapp: other' %}">go to other page </a>
<br/>
<a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}"> admin page</a>
<br/>
<a href="{% url 'admin':index %}"> admin page</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could not parse the remainder: '>0' from 'forloop.counter>0'

I got this error !!!

if its a TemplateSyntaxError then just correct your spaces between the code
For example:

( wrong statement ) {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 and forloop.counter>0 and not forloop.last %}

( right statement )  {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 and forloop.counter > 0 and not forloop.last %}
space between ( forloop.counter > 0)

this worked for me

Comment: This is not directly related to the question but it gives the same error. I have the same problem and It was so helpful. Thus I give it thumb up.