# How to dynamically change a string in { % % }

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, geodjango

How can I dynamically change the url in {% %}

```
      var years = [2011, 2012,2013,2014,2015];
      var i;
      for(i=0,i< years.length,i++){
       var year = years[i]
       var datasets = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX(`{% url '${year}' %}`,{
       onEachFeature:function(feature, layer){
             layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name.toString());
         }
      });
      datasets.addTo(map);
```

I always get the: "Could not parse the remainder" error...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not parse the remainder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562559/could-not-parse-the-remainder)